# Doubts about package naming convention and project management in Java

Tags: java, package, project

I am a bit confused about package naming in Java.

I know that it's recommended to begin the package name with a domain name like:
`com.aimforthebushes.packagename` and that there is a folder structure that equals the package naming scheme: */com/aimforthebusches/packagename*

I am beginning to use IntelliJ and when a project is created it makes by default a couple of folders `src` and `out`

I have three questions:

1.- If I am following the naming convention does it means that I have to create the folder structure `com.aimforthebushes.packagename` inside `src`?

2.- Do I need to create the same folder structure for every project or can I put them all under the same domain? ie:

- */ProjectName/com/aimforthebushes/packagename*

  or
- */com/aimforthebusches/projectname/packagename*

3.- If I can put all the projects under the same domain name (and thus same folder structure) how to I do that on IntelliJ?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The reason behind this directory structuring is to maintain larger projects, easily. If your project is not that large, and you expect it not to grow to a larger size, you can omit these conventions (I don't advice it), and just create the Java files inside a directory you like.

You should read more about java packages and modules.

1. Yes
2. If you have two different projects, they should be inside different folders, because they are two different projects. But if you are talking about different modules inside a project, you can use the same directories.

For an example, you may have the following directory structure for a single project, where `basic`, `objects` and `utils` are three different modules of the same project.

```
src
    └── org
        └── thisaru
            └── myproject
                ├── basic
                ├── objects
                └── utils
```

3. You *should not* put two projects in the same directory.

Comment: Isn't a bit redundant to create a folder structure  like /ProjectName/src/com/aimforthebushes/projectname(again)/....  Wouldn't it be simpler to have all my projects under one domain structure?

Comment: But think when you have two large projects, in the same directory. It will be a mess to handle. Your build scripts will be much more complex, and if someone other  than you (Or you, after some time period) will not be able to differentiate the two projects from each other. It is a really bad practice.

Comment: I don't understand the `redundancy` you're talking about either. What is the redundant here ? The directories with the same name ?